# Want last 12months data , tried with add_months , but its throwing error in Impala

Tags: hive, impala

I've a requirement where I have to push only last 12months data from hive to impala , so
used the following query, it was success in HIVE.

```
select * from table_1 where date_ >= add_months(CAST(current_date() as string), -12,'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Now, after pushed to Impala when tried to access the table with select statement got the below error

ERROR:

```
AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: add_months(STRING, TINYINT, STRING).
```

Tried several other functions like unix_timestamp getting passed in HIVE, but facing error only in Impala.

*Please help on this, I'm new to Impala and hive*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In Impala add_months can have two parameters:

```
ADD_MONTHS(TIMESTAMP / DATE date, INT months)
```

or

```
ADD_MONTHS(TIMESTAMP / DATE date, BIGINT months)
```

Try this: `add_months(current_date(), -12)`

Comment: tried as you said, but still the same error

Comment: @Shanti The same error about wrong signature add_months(STRING, TINYINT, STRING) ?

Comment: yes facing the same signature error add_months(STRING, TINYINT, STRING).

Comment: @Shanti that means you are still passing three parameters to the add_months instead of two.

Comment: i've tried add_months(current_date(), -12) itself and got above as error